# Cannot access Azure VM anymore

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

Following on from the latest Azure maintenance, we cannot remote desktop to one of our VMs and fix potential issue on the IIS server of this machine. Everything was working fine for over 1 year.

The Agent status is now set to "Not Ready" when looking at the properties of the VM in the Azure portal.

We obviously tried to restart the machine but no effect. We cannot redeploy the machine to another node as the VM agent seems to be down.

The outbound NSG rules do not block outbound connection to internet (so that the machine should be able to write to its azure storage).

This user seems to have a similar issue on a VM scale set: [Azure VM scale sets not accessible and cannot restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48093121/azure-vm-scale-sets-not-accessible-and-cannot-restart)

Any idea on how to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Open a support ticket

Comment: @CSharpRocks I did ! I created a Sev A ticket one day ago and still nobody has contacted me since... Hence my question here..

Comment: This "hack" may work: send a tweet to @AzureSupport explaining that you opened a ticket and it's been 24 hours without answers.

Comment: Do you have any VM extensions installed?

Comment: this was due to the latest maintenance on Azure. They updated all VMs to the latest OS. Some unapplied patches caused the problem. The product group could have re-enabled RDP to resolve the issue but it was quicker for me to rebuild my VM from scratch...